# Assemble with nasm including only referenced blocks of code/data

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

In writing some simple libraries for nasm, I noticed that labels that aren't actually called or referenced are still included in the binary.

Is there any way avoid including unused labels and their corresponding code in the object when building / compiling / assembling with nasm?

Comment: Use `.label` to make local labels.  YASM defaults to not including non-global labels in the symbol table of the output.  (It does include them if you use `-gdwarf2` to emit debug info.)  I'm not sure if there's anything you can do with NASM to disable regular symbols from going in the symbol table, other than `strip`.

Comment: @PeterCordes It's not just the symbols, it also that the code that the symbol points to is included. I think I might have to resort to some hackish macros to get it to do this, but I would rather not.

Answer (score 2):

The technology for this already exists in the form of static libraries.

Put every separable group of code+data in a separate `.o`, and build a static library (`.a`) from all those objects (using `ar`).

Linking with this static library will automatically pull in only the objects (`.o` library members) necessary to satisfy dependencies.  (And AFAIK, this works recursively, pulling in other library objects to satisfy unresolved symbols in the initial set of objects).

Comment: It would probably better to say that it will automatically pull in only the object files (`.o` files) that contain the referenced symbols.

Comment: @RossRidge: Thanks; I meant to say that, but after editing didn't notice that I hadn't!  I didn't find any exact duplicates in a quick search.  Several questions about *how* to create a static library, but none where the question wasn't already looking for one.  TODO: link one of the good library-creation answers, I guess.